# Errors while using asyncio in Python 3.6 to execute terminal commands

Tags: python-3.6, python-asyncio

I am using asyncio for the first time and I am getting these two errors: 
1) RuntimeError: set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread
2) RuntimeError: Cannot add child handler, the child watcher does not have a loop attached

Usage scenario:
I have to execute two terminal commands, one followed by another. To ensure the second command gets executed only after the first, I'm using asyncio to set the loops and running them. 
I am trying to execute a function in this python file using a flask api ultimately.
Has someone come across these errors and can guide me to resolve it?
Any help would be great!
Code:

```
async def segmentVide(command):
process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
    command,
    stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = await process.communicate()
asyncio.get_child_watcher()
return stdout.decode().strip() 

def segmentOutput(folderCreated):
    #command = MP4Box terminal command
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.get_child_watcher().attach_loop(loop)
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    coro = loop.run_in_executor(None, segmentVide, command)
    loop.run_until_complete(coro)
    loop.close()
    print('completed')
```

There is another function executing the other terminal command but the asyncio usage part is the same in it too.

Comment: Please include your code in your question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to **re-organize** your questions and learn [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @EricJohnson I have attached the relevant part of the code, do let me know if you need additional info.

Comment: @Hearen Okay will do so